# Django -File field not showing the selected file name

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

When I fill out the form and select an image to use, it  all works fine and it gets uploaded and saves to my model as expected but for some reason the field wont show the name of the file I am trying to use
[File upload field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHy55.png)

This is my forms.py, and I am using crispy forms to render my form to the template. {{forms|crispy}}
I am wondering is there anyway I can make it so it does show the name of the file I have chosen

```
class TeamCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['name','image','looking_for_members','interests' ]
```

You can see in the photo that it doesn't change but it does add the image as expected, I am using crispy forms to style the form.

Comment: You mean after having uploaded the image? Or it doesn't show it when you've selected an image but still before pressing the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

The file field is one of the more complex items in the bootstrap framework. It requires extra js to enable the file name functionality you describe. See the file field docs. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Which version of crispy forms are you using. This additional JS was added in v.1.8.1 to the template. see the pr here.

https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/pull/920